# compiling a c++ project using vs_BuildTools

Tags: visual-studio, github

i am trying to build this GitHub project [VSFilter](https://github.com/v0lt/VSFilter), in this project the "build_vsfilter.cmd" has this line "MSBuild.exe VSFilter.sln ..." so i downloaded [Build Tools for Visual Studio 2022](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/), and now i have MSBuild.exe in this folder "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools", but **how do i connect the project folder to the buildTools folder?**
please help.

i also have VS Code installed - if it's of any relevance-

running build_vsfilter.cmd file returns this error:

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

------------------------------
[ERROR] VSFilter.sln Release x86 - Compilation failed
```

also tried this in "Visual Studio 2022 Developer Command Prompt v17.8.3"

```
cd C:\VSFilter-master
MSBuild.exe VSFilter.sln /nologo /consoleloggerparameters:Verbosity=minimal /maxcpucount /nodeReuse:true /target:Build /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=x86
```

and it returned this errors:

```
C:\VSFilter-master\src\DSUtil\DSUtil.vcxproj(27,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microso
ft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found. Confirm that the
 expression in the Import declaration "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft
\VC\v170\\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
C:\VSFilter-master\src\ExtLib\VirtualDub\system\system.vcxproj(26,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program F
iles (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found
. Confirm that the expression in the Import declaration "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools
\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
C:\VSFilter-master\external\BaseClasses.vcxproj(27,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\Micr
osoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found. Confirm that
the expression in the Import declaration "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\MSBuild\Micros
oft\VC\v170\\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
C:\VSFilter-master\src\filters\transform\BaseVideoFilter\BaseVideoFilter.vcxproj(27,3): error MSB4019: The imported pro
ject "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.pr
ops" was not found. Confirm that the expression in the Import declaration "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Stud
io\2022\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" is correct, and that the file exists on disk
.
C:\VSFilter-master\src\filters\transform\VSFilter\VSFilter.vcxproj(28,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Progr
am Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not f
ound. Confirm that the expression in the Import declaration "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildT
ools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
C:\VSFilter-master\src\ExtLib\zlib\zlib.vcxproj(27,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\Micr
osoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found. Confirm that
the expression in the Import declaration "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\MSBuild\Micros
oft\VC\v170\\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
C:\VSFilter-master\src\SubPic\SubPic.vcxproj(27,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microso
ft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found. Confirm that the
 expression in the Import declaration "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft
\VC\v170\\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
C:\VSFilter-master\src\Subtitles\Subtitles.vcxproj(27,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\M
icrosoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found. Confirm th
at the expression in the Import declaration "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\MSBuild\Mic
rosoft\VC\v170\\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
C:\VSFilter-master\src\ExtLib\VirtualDub\Kasumi\Kasumi.vcxproj(26,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program F
iles (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found
. Confirm that the expression in the Import declaration "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools
\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
```

Answer (score 0):

i used [Visual Studio Community](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/free-developer-offers/) and this particular projects needs [Yasm](https://yasm.tortall.net/Download.html) then i created environments.bat to the main project folder and added this:

```
SET YASM_PATH="C:\yasm\vsyasm-1.3.0-win32\vsyasm.exe"
```

"C:\yasm\vsyasm-1.3.0-win32" is the location where i exctared yasm.

welp that's it!